# Number in ordered list on its separate line?

Tags: html, css

How can I have the number on its separate line? I need this because I want to export the HTML to an EPUB and the screen space is limited, especially when I have four digit numbers it takes up horizontal space on the line.

All the items are English phrases with their phonetic transcription. So I have two paragraphs in each list item, one is the phrase itself and the other paragraph is the phonetic transcription.

```
<ol>
  <li>
     <p>Phrase</p>
     <p>Phonetic transcription</p>
  </li>

  <li>
     <p>Phrase</p>
     <p>Phonetic transcription</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

[image]

I was wondering if it would be possible to put the number in a box, like specifying the four borders on it `1px solid #000;` to make it look a little bit more stylish.

I think the easier path would be to not use an ordered list but in that case I need to insert the number manually and in case a phrase or two gets deleted updating the numbers will be hell. So, in my case an unordered list would work better. Right?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the use of counter you don't have to insert the numbers manually, here is the code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Phrase</p>
        <p>Phonetic transcription</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Phrase</p>
        <p>Phonetic transcription</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
ul {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
    content: counter(item);
    counter-increment: item;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**EDIT:** Counters don't work in EPUB. You have to write numbers manually:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="number">1</span>
        <p>Phrase</p>
        <p>Phonetic transcription</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="number">2</span>
        <p>Phrase</p>
        <p>Phonetic transcription</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.number {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: The question is if the counter is understood by ebook readers. I'll see how it works and report back. Thank you. If I create a new `ul` is it possible to start the counter from a specific number? I will split up my EPUB in multiple chapters but the counting will continue as left off in the previous chapter.

Comment: Also, what is the point of using counter? I mean the `ol` does what I need. When I meant manually I meant to use something like `<div>1</div>`, `<div>2</div>`

Comment: @ZoltanKing Yes, you can set counter to number you want with: `counter-set: name number`

Comment: @ZoltanKing As far as I know it's impossible to style numbers in `ol` so you have to use counter to add numbers and style them, you can change `ul` to `ol` if you want, it won't change anything.

Comment: Thank you. I tried something like `<ul start="10">` in the second list but it doesn't work. I would like to have multiple lists but each one to continue where the previous left off. I need to split the EPUB into chapters that's why.

Comment: @ZoltanKing remove `counter-reset: item` from `ul` and add `counter-set: item` to `body` in css

Comment: This counter thing doesn't seem to be compatible with ebooks. When I open the EPUB all items are set to `1` even though in the HTML in a web browser the numbering shows up in order. Anyway, I appreciate your time and I'll keep the best answer. If you could eventually give me an idea where to look next I would be grateful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243955/discussion-between-zielvna-and-zoltan-king).